# 808 bass drum schematic : explanation

Tags: schematics, transfer-function

I am curious about this schematic (I would develop a project around this machine)
I was trying to understand how this bass drum work, but sounds complicated for me...

The trigger input is a pulse.

So : I already get some stuff :

I think there is a bridged T network filter around the First OA : C41/C42 + R166 and Q43.
I guess Q43 is for starting oscillator ?

I am actually trying to get the transfert function of this simplified part of the schem :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQNtwU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I think i can simplified the schem by that, but I can't find the transfert function !
(I don't know exactly how to start..., also because I don't know what s will be the load, after the OA.

Thanks for you re help, have a nice day !
Vivien

[image: tr 808 bass drum schem]

Comment: Why don't you download LTSpice - it's free of course and learn to use it. I'm not kidding when I say this will answer the above question and plenty more besides.

Comment: ey thanks for your answer, I have adready download LTSpice, the schematics works (obviously...) and I found documentation on the schem, and bridged Tnetwork too. it's not really clear yet, but better and better

Answer (score 1):

I'd download LTSpice and get to grips with how to use it. Once you have got a circuit drawn you can do transient analysis (or AC analysis) and with simple op-amp circuits get really good results.

Yes, there is a steep learning curve but it has to be done if you wish to improve your repertoire - I use a different suite of simulation tools but I've used LTS in the past and basically, I can say, that using a simulator cuts out at least one PCB iteration.

Comment: the point is, with ltspice you can get the response of the circuit, but not its transfer function, and that's I would like to get.
I found this paper [link](http://tf.boulder.nist.gov/general/pdf/2526.pdf) about bridged T network, just the network, without AOP.

So it's seem interesting, but I can't understand these equations, the firsts ones.
I know this rules, (node rule ?)
at one node :
i1 + i2 + i3 + ... =0
So, you write the equation with voltages :
Y1(V1 - Vnode) + Y2(V2- Vnode) + ... = 0
But i never saw this equations write like this !

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Maybe a mathematical analysis of the circuit is needed. I'll think about that a bit later. It won't be difficult but right now I'm being summoned!

Comment: As a start, at low frequencies the gain is unity and, at high frequencies the feedback thru the caps also means unity gain. Somewhere in between there is a peak in the responce ie it is a band-amplifier.

Comment: I got the Transfert fonction !
Based on the simplified schemas, with removing OA (just by keeping Resistances and Capa, 

T = [ R1 C1 p + 1/(R2 C2 p) + 1 + C1/C2  ]  /  [R1/R2 + R1C1p + 1/(R2C2p) + 1 + C1/C2]

And if you change : R1= aR; R2 = R/a; C1=C2=C
You obtain the TF I send you (the external link) !

Comment: Just write node eq at Vr2 and Vout, with Y instead Z.


So, that was the first step ^^ : This eq work only if Iout is null, right ? so, i guess OA compansate the current, but, it s just an hypothesis..